# List index out of range error must have an index indication

Tags: python, list

I have a `nested_list` that looks like

```
[
    ['"1"', '"Casey"', '176544.328149', '0.584286566204162', '0.415713433795838', '0.168573132408324'], 
    ['"2"', '"Riley"', '154860.665173', '0.507639071226889', '0.492360928773111', '0.0152781424537786'], 
    ['"3"', '"Jessie"', '136381.830656', '0.47783426831522', '0.52216573168478', '0.04433146336956'], 
    ['"4"', '"Jackie"', '132928.78874', '0.421132601798505', '0.578867398201495', '0.15773479640299'], 
    ['"5"', '"Avery"', '121797.419516', '0.335213073103216', '0.664786926896784', '0.329573853793568']
 ]
```

(My real `nested_list`is a very long list). And I tried to extract 2 data from each sublist and here is what I did

```
numerical_list = []
child_list = []
for l in nested_list: 
    child_list.append(l[1])
    child_list.append(float(l[2]))
    numerical_list.append(child_list)
print(numerical_list)
```

This gave me an `list index out of range` error on the line of `child_list.append(l[1])`. However, if I change that `for l in nested_list:` to `for l in nested_list[:4]:` or any range that is within the length of `nested_list`, it worked properly. This doesn't make any sense to me. Could someone help me out on finding where is wrong? Thank you~

Comment: You probably have empty nested list...you can debug using `try...except`

Comment: You test case works great. It must be an issue of one of the nested lists wich only contains a single element or is empty.

Comment: Add a print line to debug in the `for` loop, which prints your current list. Then check the record for which it is failing. The last record printed would be the culprit

Comment: There IS an element in your __real__ `nested_list` that is shorter than expected (either empty or of length 1). You don't have a proper MCVE here as it doesn't reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you guys! My nested_list is from a .csv and its last line is empty, so that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just interested in the first two elements, one way is to use `try... except`, other direct way is to check for the length of the list as following.

This way you only append the lists where the 1st and the 2nd element exist.

```
numerical_list = []
child_list = []
for l in nested_list: 
    if len(l>=3):
        child_list.append(l[1])
        child_list.append(float(l[2]))
        numerical_list.append(child_list)
print(numerical_list)
```

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that the last element of my nested_list is empty.